# How to view iTunes U without iTunes?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, itunes

I want to view Stanford's iOS programming course.

How can I see it without installing iTunes on my PC and on my Android mobile device?

Answer (score 3):

There's the free and open source **Tunes Viewer** which is sadly not available in the Play store (Apple probably doesn't allow it):

The easiest way is to install the FOSS market [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk) which hosts such apps and install **Tunes Viewer** from there (search for "TunesViewer").

It's also directly available as an .apk installation file [here](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=itunes&fdid=com.tunes.viewer), but I'd prefer the F-Droid market installation because you get updates. The project's homepage is on [SourceForge](http://tunesviewer.sourceforge.net/).

PS: *The [**F-Droid Repository**](http://f-droid.org) is an easily-installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform. The server contains the details of multiple versions of each application, and the Android client makes it easy to browse, install them onto your device, and keep track of updates.**

Comment: To be clear, Tunesviewer *was* posted on Google Play awhile ago a "University Podcasts Pro", and was removed only because the one who posted it hadn't given any credit to original authors (and was charging for a broken version of the app as well). - unfortunately this happens [pretty often](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2cbrhd/my_app_was_stolen_and_published_on_google_play_by/), and is another reason it's better to use FDroid than Google.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately , you'll have to download iTunes.. then drag the downloaded courses over to your mobile device..

Comment: Nope, there's the FOSS Tunes Viewer, but it's not on Google Play (due to licensing issues I guess). See my answer...